# SQL query based on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, date-range

I have table

| emp_id | date_time |
| --- | --- |
| e001 | 23-01-01 07:08 |
| e001 | 23-01-01 16:07 |
| e001 | 23-01-03 07:45 |
| e001 | 23-01-03 16:01 |

I want to query to show result based on date range. for example I set the date range from 23-01-01 to 23-01-03 for e001 then the result is:

| date | in | out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23-01-01 | 07:08 | 16:07 |
| 23-01-02 | null | null |
| 23-01-03 | 07:45 | 16:01 |

Comment: Seems like a calendar table and `MIN`/`MAX` is what you want. What *have* you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Also those dates are very ambiguous. Is that 01 January 2023? 1923? 23 January 1901? 1st of the 23rd of 2001?

Comment: yes its an attendance table, i have tried: SELECT emp_id, MIN(date_time) as [IN], MAX(date_time) as [OUT] WHERE date_time between '2023-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2023-01-03 23:59:59.999' but the result is not show date 2023-01-02 because no entry. what I want is the result shows date 2023-01-02 as null when no entry

Comment: This is why, as I mentioned, you need a calendar table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your example data, and turning it into some DDL/DML (this is a really helpful first step you should do when asking these types of questions):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (emp_id VARCHAR(4), date_time DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @Table (emp_id, date_time) VALUES
('e001', '2023-01-01 07:08'),
('e001', '2023-01-01 16:07'),
('e001', '2023-01-03 07:45'),
('e001', '2023-01-03 16:01');
```

This becomes a simple exercise in data extrapolation to make sure we have rows for each interval. We can do this simply using a `CTE`. Then, joining from the full data set back to an aggregation of the table (assuming you just want the first date time as the IN and the last as the OUT where they don't match).

Finally, just apply the predicate to limit the date range:

```
;WITH Dates AS (
SELECT MIN(CAST(date_time AS DATE)) AS mnDate, MAX(CAST(date_time AS DATE)) AS mxDate FROM @Table
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,mnDate), mxDate
  FROM Dates
 WHERE mnDate < mxDate
)

SELECT mnDate AS Date, InDateTime, OutDateTime
  FROM Dates d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                     SELECT CAST(date_time AS DATE) AS date, MIN(date_time) AS InDateTime, NULLIF(MAX(date_time),MIN(date_time)) AS OutDateTime 
                       FROM @Table 
                      GROUP BY CAST(date_time AS DATE)
                    ) a
      ON d.mnDate = a.date
 WHERE d.mnDate BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-03';
```

| Date | InDateTime | OutDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 07:08:00.000 | 2023-01-01 16:07:00.000 |
| 2023-01-02 |  |  |
| 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-03 07:45:00.000 | 2023-01-03 16:01:00.000 |

Comment: *Hopefully* the OP is working with small date ranges. If not, a tally or pre-exisiting calendar table would be a *far* more performant solution to an rCTE

Comment: An rCTE spanning two years would be less than 800 rows, which executes sub-second even on my rinky-dinky laptop. Of course if the data set is expanded to enterprise scale tuning and performance options would need to be considered, but that's likely outside of the scope of the question, I think.